# Problems getting text overlayed on an image link

Tags: html, css, overlay

OK, so this may be getting too complicated for CSS/HTML to handle, but I may as well ask.

I have some dynamically placed images using the code from [here](http://css-tricks.com/equidistant-objects-with-css/).
What I would like to add to those images, is a text overlay with a transparent background.
Something like [this](http://css-tricks.com/text-blocks-over-image/).

I think the issue is to do with the floated images. Also possibly the fact that my images are also links. I've tried a lot of variations and guides, but just can't seem to figure out why it's not working. I don't care about the images having opacity, I don't think that's affecting things. Current code gets the text next to the image. Example can be seen [here](http://baradineholdings.com.au/gallery.php).

**HTML;**

```
<div id="internal">
    <div id="row2">
        <a href="studies.php"><img src="images/gallery/studies/STUDY1.jpg" width="200" height="200" alt="Studies Gallery"/></a><h2><span>Some text.</span></h2>
        <div id="movers-row2">
            <div><a href="mediaunits.php"><img src="images/gallery/mediaunits/media1.JPG" width="200" height="200" alt="Media Units Gallery"/></a></div>
            <div><a href="freestandingfurniture.php"><img src="images/gallery/freestandingfurniture/furniture1.JPG" width="200" height="200" alt="Furniture Gallery"/></a></div>
        </div> <!-- end #movers -->
    </div> <!-- end #row -->
    <div style="clear: both;"></div>
</div> <!-- end #internal -->
```

CSS;

```
#internal
{
    width: 958px;
    height: auto;
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

#row2 {
    min-width: 480px;
    display: block;
    border: 0px;
}

#row2 a img {
    position: relative;
    background-color: black;
    opacity: 0.7; /* transparent */
    filter:alpha(opacity=70); /* IE transparent */
}

#row2 h2 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
}

#row2 span {
    color: white;
    font: bold 24px Helvetica;
    letter-spacing: -1px;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    padding: 10px;
}

#movers-row2 {
    margin: -204px 0 0 200px;
    height: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#movers-row2 div {
    width: 49.9%;
    float: left;
}

#movers-row2 div img {
    float: right;
}
```

Comment: Can you put up an example with your images at jsFiddle?

Comment: I don't think I can upload images on jsFiddle?
What extra information do you need? I don't really like jsFiddle (or think it will help), it doesn't always render things properly compared to using an actual browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some people over at css-tricks.com helped me out with the solution;

[Solution](http://css-tricks.com/forums/discussion/comment/63950#Comment_63950)

Answer (score 0):

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/7573777/z_working-folder/stacko.html

If you apply opacity to the container that holds the background image and the main content area is white behind it and you apply opacity to the h2 background which holds the span with the non faded text, the effect is lost in the two opacities. The text is white so it seems faded too. For the positioning, I'm wondering if the above link will work for you. :)

Comment: That seems to work fine, the only problem I have with that is that the "hippo" class is not dynamic. You've made it a set 401px. Is there a way around this?

Ideally, I would like text to be centred on the image, again, dynamic would be best if possible.

Comment: I don't really know what you mean by dynamic. The example link you gave: http://css-tricks.com/text-blocks-over-image/ has absolute positioning and is a static layout. If by dynamic you mean something like responsive/flexible grid/liquid, I'm pretty sure you could use percents to do that. You just need to position the text/headings where you like, like in your first example: http://css-tricks.com/equidistant-objects-with-css/. Maybe I'm not understanding your issue.

Comment: Well I want the text overlay on all 3 images, plus if I think have further images below, having a set height of 401px from the top isn't going to work. Hence, dynamically placed, like the images. I might even have 4 images in the row, again, that would mean I need the text overlays to be dynamic.

Comment: Oh, then just change position: relative; on h2.hippo and top: to something like 100px; Now the container of h2 is relative to itself and can be positioned relative to its containing element (div#row2) and you could set a top margin of whatever you like (even a negative number) on div#row2 to reduce the gap between it and the element above it. :)